# getSelection returning text after cleared

Tags: javascript

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FTQyh/)

**JS**

```
function getSelectionHtml() {
    var html = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
        }
    }
    console.log(html);  <-- returning text even not selected.
}

$(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).bind("mouseup", getSelectionHtml);
});
```

I'm currently trying to understand the following behavior:

1) Select a few lines of text (console.log shows those lines) - expected.

2) Click within the selection you've made. Console.log then shows the same text as the previous, which was selected. - Not expected; here I expect getSelection to return nothing as nothing is currently selected.

Can anyone tell me what i'm missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FTQyh/6/)

**JS**

```
var previousText = '';
function getSelectionHtml() {
    var html = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
        }
    }
    if(html!= previousText) {
        console.log(html);
    }
    previousText = html;
}

$(document).mousedown(function () {}).mouseup( function () {
    getSelectionHtml();
});
```

To not show empty selections just change:

```
if(html!= previousText) {
```

to this:

```
if(html!= previousText && html != '') {
```

*Note: I'm using jQuery because you were too*

Comment: Simple and elegant, I kept trying to think of all these complex solutions.  Thank You!!